# Can't import a model in odoo view

Tags: python, ubuntu, model, odoo, odoo-10

I have installed odoo 10 on linux and it works fine
I'm following the official tutorial from odoo website 'building a module'

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html#build-an-odoo-module

I have created an empty module with

```
odoo-bin scaffold openacademy addons
```

but when I try to import a module in to the xml file **openacademy.xml** I get the following error

```
Error context:
View `course.form`

[view_id: 4867, xml_id: n/a, model: openacademy.course, parent_id: n/a]
None" while parsing /opt/odoo/odoo-

10.0/addons/openacademy/views/openacademy.xml:6, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="course_form_view">
        <field name="name">course.form</field>
        <field name="model">openacademy.course</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Course Form">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="description"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

**openacademy.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="course_form_view">
            <field name="name">`course.form`</field>
            <field name="model">`openacademy.course`</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Course Form">
                    <sheet>
                        <group>
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="description"/>
                        </group>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>  
  </data>
</odoo>
```

**models.py**

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class Course(models.Model):
_name = 'openacademy.course'

name = fields.Char(string="Title", required=True)
description = fields.Text()
```

**__init__.py**

```
from . import models
```

Comment: Fix your indentation and why do you have backticks (``) all over the place in your xml code?

Comment: @danidee I've fixed the indentation but still the view doesn't recognize the model

Answer (score 0):

In the **__init__.py**  just try using

```
import models
```

Comment: I have 2  **__init__.py**  files and both have `import models`, any other suggestions?

Comment: what is your folder structure for this module?

Comment: it's the basic structure created with `odoo-bin scaffold openacademy addons` command, 3 folders (views, modules, controllers)

Comment: it's ok I've solved the problem,I've just created another empty model and copied my files there, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

try replace this code :

```
 <field name="name">course.form</field>
 <field name="model">openacademy.course</field>
```

You can not use "''" in XML, it will cause the error.
And then rest some space at the beginning of rows like this

```
 from odoo import models, fields, api
 class Course(models.Model):
      _name = "openacademy.course"

      name = fields.Char(string="Title", required=True)
      description = fields.Text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the sample "building a module" **init**.py (from https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html) it is importing the model under addons/openacademy/models.

In my case, I have to restart odoo (kill the current odoo-bin and restart). The error on importing "openacademy.course" went away, and installation was successful.